# Visual Studio 2019 how to change start action on ASP.NET Core web project

Tags: asp.net-core

Using Visual Studio 2019 when working on an ASP.NET framework web project, if I pull up the Properties page, there is a Web tab under the References tab, where you can select the Start Action and you can set it to 'Current Page'. I find this really useful as when you hit F5, IIS Express starts and the debugger will run the page that you are working on and have currently selected.

I'm now working on an ASP.NET Core Razor pages web project and the Web tab on the Properties page has disappeared, and it doesn't matter what page I am editing or have selected, when I click Start Debugging or Start Without Debugging, VS always loads the site Index page - so then I have to either navigate to the page I want to debug, or manually edit the URL on the browser.

Can anyone please tell me how to change the Start Action to 'Current Page' in a Core web project, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it from here **Properties -> launchSettings.json**
Inside launchSettings.json you will find this JSON.

```
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3134",
  "sslPort": 0
}
```

}

Change the applicationUrl as per your requirement. Your application will start from that URL.

Comment: Thanks for that info - I guess you would have to manually change it each time. Pity there isn't an option to always run the currently selected file, I wonder why they dumped that option...

Comment: Right-click on the view (.cshtml) file and select "View in Browser" . This might help you in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't spotted that. Guess it's equivalent to Ctrl-F5. They should add the option "Debug in Browser"